# What does ISO-8859 in `file` mean?

Tags: file, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1, iconv

I ran the following command in a software repository I have access to:

> find . -not -name "*.svn*" -type f -exec file "{}" \;

and saw many output lines like

> ./File.java: ISO-8859 C++ program text

What does that mean? ISO-8859 is an encoding **class**, not a certain encoding. I've expected all files to be UTF-8, but most are in the presented encoding. Is ISO-8859 a proper subset of UTF-8, too?

Is it possible for me to convert all those files safely by using ISO-8859-1 as source encoding while translating it into UTF-8 with `iconv` for example?

Comment: _Edit_: While compiling the Java sources, I get warnings indicating that there is no appropriate mapping for german umlauts.

Comment: @KoeingGunther You have to compile your Java program with the correct encoding specified, like `java -encoding UTF-8` or `java -encoding MacRoman` or `java -encoding ISO-8859-15` or whatever you are using. Java has a design flaw whereby there is no way internal to the file to specify the encoding. Yes, this means you could do wicked things like `java -encoding UTF-16LE` or whatnot; perhaps they construe that to be a feature, although I do not.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that the Unix `file` program is rather bad at this. It just means it is in a byte encoding.  It does not mean that it is ISO-8859-1.  It might even be in a non-ISO byte encdidng, although it usually figures that out.

I have a system that does much better than file, but it is trained on an English-language corpus, so might not do as well as on German.

The short answer is that the result of `file` is not reliable.  You have to know the real encoding to up-convert it.

Answer (score 0):

The charset detection used by `file` is rather simplistic.  It recognizes UTF-8.  And it distinguished between "ISO-8859" and "non-ISO extended-ASCII" by looking for bytes in the 0x80-0x9F range where the ISO 8859 encodings have "holes".  But it makes no attempt to determine *which* ISO 8859 encoding is in use.  Which is why it just says `ISO-8859` instead of `ISO-8859-1` or `ISO-8859-15`.